# I want to return two results from one function in php

Tags: php, android, mysql, xml, web-services

Here is my function in DB_Functions.php, i want to get two different values from two different tables in single function only here is the code what i have tried so far but the values are coming null.

```
 public function getUserMetvalue($exname,$fname) {

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT metvalue FROM fitnessactivitylist WHERE activityname='$exname'") or die(mysql_error());

     $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT weight FROM users WHERE name='$fname'") or die(mysql_error());

       // check for result

       $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
       $no_of_rowss = mysql_num_rows($result1);


      if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
          $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
          if ($no_of_rowss > 0) {
              $result1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
              return $result1;
          }                        
          return $result;
      } else {
         //exercise name not found
         return false;
      }
    }
```

here is my index.php

```
       //TAG METVALUE
      if ($tag == 'metvalue') {

      $exname =  $_POST['exname'];

      $fname =  $_POST['fname'];

      $usermetvalue = $db->getUserMetvalue($exname,$fname);

      if ($usermetvalue != false) {

      $response["success"] = 1;

     $response["usermetvalue"]["exname"] = $usermetvalue["exname"];

      $response["usermetvalue"]["fname"] = $usermetvalue["fname"];

      echo json_encode($response);

        }

                else {

 $response["error"] = 1;
 $response["error_msg"] = "No exercise found!";
 echo json_encode($response);

          }

    }
```

Comment: Please don't use mysql_ since it's deprecated.

Comment: I wish I could un-see that.

Comment: Lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities.

Comment: Let the function return an array. Then you can return as many values as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spot the differences:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT metvalue etc...
                              ^^^^^^^^
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT weight etc...
                               ^^^^^^


$response["usermetvalue"]["exname"] = $usermetvalue["exname"];
                                                     ^^^^^^
$response["usermetvalue"]["fname"] = $usermetvalue["fname"];
                                                    ^^^^^
```

You fetch fields which aren't used later, then attempt to access fields which weren't fetched in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

```
 function a_function() {
     $a = 'Learn';
     $b = 'Programming.';

     return array($a, $b);
 }

 list($one, $two) = a_function();

 echo $one . ' ' . $two;
```